# Can 3D OpenGL game written in Python look good and run fast?

Tags: python, opengl

I am planning to write an simple 3d(isometric view) game in Java using jMonkeyEngine - nothing to fancy, I just want to learn something about OpenGL and writing efficient algorithms (random map generating ones).

When I was planning what to do, I started wondering about switching to Python. I know that Python didn't come into existence to be a tool to write 3d games, but is it possible to write good looking games with this language?

I have in mind 3d graphics, nice effects and free CPU time to power to rest of game engine? I had seen good looking java games - and too be honest, I was rather shocked when I saw level of detail achieved in Runescape HD.

On the other hand, pygame.org has only 2d games, with some starting 3d projects. Are there any efficient 3d game engines for python? Is pyopengl the only alternative? Good looking games in python aren't popular or possible to achieve?

I would be grateful for any information / feedback.

Comment: Here are some modules you should check [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL), [pygame](https://www.pygame.org), [pymunk](https://github.com/viblo/pymunk) [pyglet](https://www.pyglet.org)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are worried about 3D performance: Most of the performance-critical parts will be handled by OpenGL (in a C library or even in hardware), so the language you use to drive it should not matter too much.

To really find out if performance is a problem, you'd have to try it. But there is no reason why it cannot work in principle.

At any rate, you could still optimize the critical parts, either in Python or by dropping to C. You still gain Python's benefit for most of the game engine which is less performance-critical.

Comment: Use [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) instead of PyOpenGL. Easy and fast and no ctypes required. It is not a game engine but access to the OpenGL in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Eve Online does it.

http://support.eve-online.com/Pages/KB/Article.aspx?id=128

Comment: However it's worth noting that much of Eve is implemented in C++. It is held together by Python however.

Answer (score 4):

I did a EuroPython talk about my amateur attempts to drive OpenGL from Python:
http://pyvideo.org/video/381/pycon-2011--algorithmic-generation-of-opengl-geom

The latest version of the code I'm talking about is here:
https://github.com/tartley/gloopy

It's billed as a 'library', but that was naive of me: It's a bunch of personal experimental code.

Nevertheless, it demonstrates that you can move around hundreds of bits of geometry at 60fps from Python.

Although the demo above is fairly bare-bones in that it uses simply geometry and untextured faces, one thing I found is that more detailed geometry, texture mapping or other more modern graphics effects don't substantially affect the framerate. Or at least they don't affect it any worse than using the same effects in a C program. These are run on the GPU, so it doesn't make any difference at all if your program is written in Python.

One thing that is performance-sensitive from Python is if you are creating dynamic geometry on the CPU side, e.g. moving individual vertices within a shape, by bending or melting the shape. Doing this sort of per-vertex calculation in Python, then constructing a new ctypes array from the result, then shunting this geometry to the GPU, every frame, will be slow. Instead you should probably be doing this in a vertex shader.

On the other hand, if you just want affine transformations (moving objects around, rotating them, opening chests of drawers, rotating car wheels, bending a jointed robot arm) then all of this can be done by the GPU and the fact your program is written in Python makes little difference to the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Python-Ogre](http://www.python-ogre.org/). I just messed with it myself, nothing serious, but seems pretty good.

Comment: I've been thinking of doing a re-write for WiiTanks on the PC, and had been toying with PyGame... but Ogre looks rather promising - thanks very much for the link!

Comment: @JonCage Did you ever write this in Python?

Comment: I got some of the basics working but nothing worth releasing.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) which is a similar system to pygame, but with full bindings to OpenGL. You can start with simple 2D games to get the hang of the system and work up to 3D later. It is a more modern system than PyGame which is built around SDL which itself is a bit long in the tooth these days.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a wee bit off topic but, if your goal is to learn Python, how about creating a game using [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.com/) and [XNA](http://www.xna.com/)? XNA is not OpenGL though, yet I find it an extremely simple 2D/3D engine which is fast and supports Shader Model 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Frets on Fire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/screenshots/) project -- an open source Guitar Hero alternative. It's written in Python and has decent 3D graphics in OpenGL. I would suggest checking out [its sources](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/documentation/source/) for hints on libraries etc.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Vampires game out a few years ago where most if not all of the code was in Python. Not sure if the 3D routines were in them, but it worked fine.